# How to join two table functions

Tags: sql-server

Hi have to table functions.
the one is

```
select * from [dbo].[GetMembersofGroupPolicy](21929,getdate())
```

this functions returns a table where one column is named EntityID.
what i need is to execute my second table function which is

```
select * from  dbo.GetFamilyMembers(EntityID)
```

for each EntityID i will get as` result from the first table.
what i tried is

```
    SELECT F.ParentID, F.Relation, GM.ID_SYMBOLAIOY, GM.TIN, 
    GM.[LastName Native], 
    GM.[FirstName Native], 
    GM.[LastName Eng], 
    GM.[FirstName Eng], 
    GM.DOB, 
    GM.EntryDate, 
    GM.EntityID, 
    GM.TerminationDate, 
    GM.isActive
    FROM 
    dbo.GetMembersofGroupPolicy(21929, GETDATE()) AS GM 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT id_ypokat, ParentID, prnt, id_ontot_child, Relation
     FROMdbo.GetFamilyMembers(GM.EntityID) AS GetFamilyMembers_1) AS F 
     ON GM.EntityID = F.id_ontot_child
```

but i am getting an error that entityID could not be bound.

Can anybody help me to edit this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are in need of the APPLY and CROSS APPLY functions in SQL:

> The APPLY operator allows you to invoke a table-valued function for each row returned by an outer table expression of a query. The table-valued function acts as the right input and the outer table expression acts as the left input. The right input is evaluated for each row from the left input and the rows produced are combined for the final output. The list of columns produced by the APPLY operator is the set of columns in the left input followed by the list of columns returned by the right input.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx

```
SELECT F.ParentID, F.Relation, GM.ID_SYMBOLAIOY, GM.TIN, 
GM.[LastName Native], 
GM.[FirstName Native], 
GM.[LastName Eng], 
GM.[FirstName Eng], 
GM.DOB, 
GM.EntryDate, 
GM.EntityID, 
GM.TerminationDate, 
GM.isActive
FROM 
dbo.GetMembersofGroupPolicy(21929, GETDATE()) AS GM 
OUTER APPLY
(SELECT id_ypokat, ParentID, prnt, id_ontot_child, Relation
 FROMdbo.GetFamilyMembers(GM.EntityID)) AS F
```

Hopefully this helps or at least puts you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the value of the row as part of a derived table like that. You need to use APPLY for this.

```
SELECT F.ParentID
    , F.Relation
    , GM.ID_SYMBOLAIOY
    , GM.TIN
    , GM. [LastName Native]
    , GM.[FirstName Native]
    , GM.[LastName Eng]
    , GM.[FirstName Eng]
    , GM.DOB
    , GM.EntryDate
    , GM.EntityID
    , GM.TerminationDate
    , GM.isActive
FROM dbo.GetMembersofGroupPolicy(21929, GETDATE()) AS GM 
cross apply dbo.GetFamilyMembers(GM.EntityID) AS F
where GM.EntityID = F.id_ontot_child
```

Paul White has an awesome 2 article series on APPLY.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69953/

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/APPLY/69954/

Make sure you really have inline table valued functions here. If there is more than a single query the performance is likely going to suffer horribly.

Comment: my only problem now is that actually i need a left join. because now is shows me only records that have values in second table function. can you please help?

Comment: Read the articles I referenced. CROSS APPLY works similar to an inner join. OUTER APPLY works similar to a left join.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].GetMembersofGroupPolicy(21929, GETDATE()) AS GM 

outer apply dbo.GetFamilyMembers(GM.EntityID) as F
```

Use Cross Apply if you want to mimic inner join behavior.